# Javascript regex for accepting only number without "," or "." character

Tags: javascript, regex, integer

I'm looking for a regex javascript expression for allowing only numbers at this format 1234. Not 1,234 or 1.234. I'm having this regex now but it does not seem to work properly `/[a-z]/i`

Comment: Sorry, but what does `/[a-z]/i`  regex has to do with numbers? What was your intent? How did you use it?

Answer (score 3):

```
var reg = /^\d+$/;
```

should do it. The original matches anything that consists of exactly one digit.